# How can we sort data based on date in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting, aggregate

how can I sort document in ascending or descending order in MongoDB

```
const contact = await AtHome.aggregate([
    {
      $project:{
        name:1,
        partnerName:1,
        phone:1,
        email:1,
        city:1,
        guest:1,
        desc:1,
        requestedOn: { $dateToString: { format: "%d-%m-%Y", date: "$createdAt" } },
        weddingDate: { $dateToString: { format: "%d-%m-%Y", date: "$weddingDate" } },
      }
    },
    { $sort : { createdAt : -1 } }
  ]);
  try {
    res.send(contact);
  } catch (err) {
    res.send('INVALID');
  }
```

I treid to add createdAt:1 to $project object but did not work.
AtHome.js (Schema)

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const atHomeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  partnerName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  phone: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  weddingDate: {
    type: Date,
    required: false
  },
  city: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  guest: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  desc: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  createdAt:{
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now()
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('AtHome', atHomeSchema);
```

I added AtHome.js which is my schema file

This is what I tried but not working, I am just getting the unsorted document
Please help me
Thank You

Comment: please, send your `AtHome` schema.

Comment: add `createdAt: 1` to `$project` object.

Comment: @MahdiHashemi
`const atHomeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  partnerName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  phone: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  weddingDate: {
    type: Date,
    required: false
  },
  city: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  guest: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  desc: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  createdAt:{
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now()
  }
});
`

Comment: don't send that in the comment section, update your question.

Comment: @MahdiHashemi
add createdAt: 1 to $project object.
did not worked

Comment: @MahdiHashemi I updated my questing, Please check now

Comment: sort your result before the project that, it may be work.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [Aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/), you have to first sort the data and then project it to desired output. Try the following query:

```
const contact = await AtHome.aggregate([
{ $sort : { createdAt : -1 } },
{ $project: {
        name:1,
        partnerName:1,
        phone:1,
        email:1,
        city:1,
        guest:1,
        desc:1,
        requestedOn: { $dateToString: { format: "%d-%m-%Y", date: "$createdAt" } },
        weddingDate: { $dateToString: { format: "%d-%m-%Y", date: "$weddingDate" } },
      }
    }
  ]);

  try {
    res.send(contact);
  } catch (err) {
    res.send('INVALID');
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the above answers you need to sort the data before project. I can see the in you `Schema` that you are using `default: Date.now()` for the `createdAt`, this will set the value of `createdAt` to time when `Schema` is defined, So all the records will have same value for `createdAt` until next restart of the server. You can use `Date.now` instead, if you need to set the `createdAt` to time when the record is created

```js
  createdAt:{
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the `createdAt` field in projection or change the order of pipeline stages `$sort` then `$project`.

Each stage transforms the documents as they pass through the pipeline. In your first stage, you have filtered out `createdAt` so the second stage doesn't take any effect. It is recommended to use `$sort` before `$project` stage so `$sort` stage may use index. [This will provide better performance](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/index.html#sort-operator-and-performance).

```
// sort order 1 -> asc, -1 ->desc    
await AtHome.aggregate([ {$sort : { createdAt : 1 }} ,{$project : {...}}])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your first step should be to understand how aggregation pipeline works. In pipeline stages, the data goes from one stage to another.On each stage we do some modifications in data and that modified data is passed on to next pipeline stage.

Here your first stage is project which return the fields you specified:
[image]

and this data is then passed on to sorting stage and as the sort stage can not find createdAt field in data from first stage, so unsorted data is returned.

So add

```
const contact = await AtHome.aggregate([
    {
      $project:{
        name:1,
        partnerName:1,
        phone:1,
        email:1,
        city:1,
        guest:1,
        desc:1,
        requestedOn: { $dateToString: { format: "%d-%m-%Y", date: "$createdAt" } },
        weddingDate: { $dateToString: { format: "%d-%m-%Y", date: "$weddingDate" } },
        createdAt : 1
      }
    },
    { $sort : { createdAt : -1 } }
  ]);
```

which gives createdAt field which sort stage can use:
[image]

Using sort as a first stage in pipeline is very bad idea. If millions of records are there then the query will be very slow. So it always good to use sort before the limit stage but after the match stage(so that we have less number of docs to sort).

Use timestamp option for createdAt and updatedAt fields in documents.

```
const schema = Schema({
  //your fields
}, {
  timestamps: true }
});
```

Read More : https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#timestamps